# How to open pdf file which is in Wordpress Media Library folder on click of button on any wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I have a very typical question.
I have a wordpress page with a button when I click on button It opens a PDF file in new Tab.
so client have to upload new pdf files every week so I cannot give them access to wordpress Admin panel to upload the pdf files so, I created a Admin Page where user will upload pdf file.
Now this recent selected pdf will go to Wordpress Media Library folder and gets saved there.
But what I want is On click of button this recent selected pdf must open so how to link this media library folder pdf with button on wordpress page?
please help.
Complete code
first the wordpress page with Button- opens pdf

```html
<div class="redbox_text"><a href="http://localhost:82/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/blank.pdf" target="_blank" title="Rulesof_Participation" id="Rulesof_Participation" class="Rulesof_Participation">Rules of Participation</a></div>
```

Now code for admin page :

```html
<?php
include_once('MediaUpload.php');
include_once('ImageMeta.php');
if($_POST){
$tmp = new MediaUpload;
$a = $tmp->saveUpload($field_name ='my_file');
var_dump($a);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="my_file" />
<p> <input type="submit" name="action" /> </p>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

MediaUpload php file

```html
<?php
class MediaUpload{
     public function __construct(){

     }
public function saveUpload( $field_name= null, $user_id= null){
   if(is_null( $field_name))
   die('Need field_name');

//Move file to the uploads directory, returns an array of information from $_FILES
$uploaded_file = $this->handleUpload( $_FILES[ $field_name ]);

 if( !isset( $uploaded_file['file']))
   return false;

//If we were to have a unique use account for uplaoding
if( is_null( $user_id)){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $user_id = $current_user->ID;
}

//Build the Global unique Identifier
$guid = $this->buildGuid( $uploaded_file['file']);

//Build our array of data to be inserted as a post
$attachment = array(
  'post_mime_type' => $_FILES[ $field_name]['type'],
  'guid' => $guid,
  'post_title' => 'Uploaded : ' . $this->mediaTitle( $uploaded_file['file'] ),
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_author' => $user_id,
  'post_status' => 'inherit',
  'post_date' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
  'post_date_gmt' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
);

//Add the file to the media library and generate thumbnail
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploaded_file['file'] );

require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php'  );
$meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_file['file'] );

$image = new ImageMeta;
$meta['image_meta']['keywords'] = $image->iptcParser('keywords', $uploaded_file['file'] );
$meta['image_meta']['city']          = $image->iptcParser('city', $uploaded_file['file'] );
$meta['image_meta']['region']      = $image->iptcParser('region', $uploaded_file['file'] );
$meta['image_meta']['country']    = $image->iptcParser('country', $uploaded_file['file'] );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $meta );

//set the feedback flag to false since the uplaod was successful
$upload_feedback = false;

return $attach_id;
}

public function handleUpload( $file=array() ){
     require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php' );
     return wp_handle_upload( $file, array( 'test_form' => false ), date('Y/m') );
}

public function buildGuid( $file=array() ){
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    return $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . _wp_relative_upload_path( $file );
}
public function mediaTitle( $file ){

}

}


?>
```

ImageMeta php file

```html
<?php
  class ImageMeta{
    public function iptcParser( $value=null, $image=null ){
      $size = getimagesize( $image, $info );
     }

 }
?>
```

Comment: If you have a problem with your teeth you bring them to the dentist to have a look. If you have a problem with your car you bring the car to the repair shop and let them have a look. Right? This seems to go smoothly. Now, let's say you have a problem with your code and need to bring it to the programmers, *what do you bring?*

Comment: Specific answer for specific question: *Start with **https://developer.wordpress.org/***

Comment: @Andreas Nice comment, I'll save this in AutoReviewComments ;)

Comment: @Bindiya The button already has the link of the associated file that you gave it. To get the new pdf file, a new link should be created on the button. Now you should think of ways to make this button aquire the new pdf file, instead of the static link that you gave it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that code.
What I would do if I didn't want to give backend access to the client, would be to make the button dynamic.
One way this could be achieved is creating a custom function that changes the link of the button with javascript.

Next step would be to let the user not only to upload pdf files, but also let him choose which pdf file to use.

So let assume that the user uploads 10 pdf files, but this week he wants to present pdf#3. You should let him choose it from a list or whatever (make a page that only lists pdf files from the media folder) and upon saving his option in a database field, make sure that the button creates a link using that same field, so as to present the end user with the correct file.

If you cannot change the code of the button, you could use a javascript method, to pass that database field as a link in the button. You have to have a constant id or class on the button though, so that javascript gets a referrence point and can actually change the href attribute.

I hope this gives you a good idea on how to achieve what you want. If you get errors in your code, dont hesitate to ask for help :)

Comment: thank you for a sec after looking at those waste comments above I thought I was asking  out of universe. thank you let me try it.